# Multiple timers on the same page don't work smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have about 3 JavaScript timers working at the same time on a page using `settimeout`, but the functions called by these timers are not working smoothly and it seems that the timers are waiting on each other, and some times hang the page.

Is there a best practice when dealing with js timers to avoid this behavior?

Examples:

Sometimes use jQuery timers like this:

```
$(document).everyTime(1000, "blinkRed", function (i) {
      $(price).toggleClass('valuered');
}, 10);
```

and sometimes I use the normal `settimeout` JavaScript function.

Comment: Can you show some (relevant) code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timers are not waiting for each other, but the functions that are called when the timer is done, are. 
So, when you put blocking code (like an alert) in the first timer function, it will prevent the other timers to go off.

Comment: Yes, javascript is single threaded, another timer will only fire after the previous one did return.

Comment: Ok, I made stuff better and smoother by increasing the timeout, to make let not too often.